# Handling Async/Await Cancellation in C# Service Application

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I have a service that spins up a thread to listen for incoming tcp stream

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    worker = new Thread(ListenForStatus);
    worker.Start();
}
```

The listen method sends the recevied tcp stream to async task for processing, does not wait for it to complete and goes back to listening for tcp stream

```
private void ListenForStatus()
{
    while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
         _ = ProcessEventAsync("string_to_process");
    }
}

private async Task ProcessEventAsync(string Status)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    //Do Something
}
```

`OnStop` method breaks the loop and terminates the thread.

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
     _shutdownEvent.Set();
     worker.Join(2000);
}
```

Program is working as intended. But do I need to handle `Cancellation` of existing async tasks when the service is stopped and how do I implement it?

Comment: You could maintain a Queue of Tasks that you check for completion and dequeue completed tasks. If you need all running tasks to stop immediately when the program is terminated, then you could iterate over the queue of incomplete tasks and cancel them manually.

Comment: @AndrewH, that is definitely one way to do it. I was wondering if there are dynamic approaches.

Comment: Does `ProcessEventAsync` do an I/O or CPU bound operations?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo CPU bound operations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way...

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   worker = new Task(ListenForStatus);
   worker.Start();
}

private void ListenForStatus()
{
    while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _ = ProcessEventAsync("...", cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}

private async Task ProcessEventAsync(string Status, CancellationToken token)
{
    // Assume that you process something for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        // you can break the loop by checking token
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;

        //Do something

        // or
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // do something
        }, token);

    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: In your implementation, the async Task doesn't check if it has been cancelled.

Comment: You can check the cancellation from given token argument. as I don't know what you want to do after checking the cancellation, I just left it as empty.

Answer (score 2):

I have `await Task.Delay()` inside `ProcessEventAsync` method that I overloaded with `CancellationToken`.

```
private async Task ProcessEventAsync(string Status, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000, token);
    //Do Something
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```